# How to read the step timings in MVC Mini Profiler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler

In MVC mini profiler, how can I extract the step timings for my own use? eg not just showing them in the little box to the top left, eg given that I have steps

```
using (var step = MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Foo"))
{
    _fooService.Foo();
}

using (var step = MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Bar"))
{
    _barService.Bar();
}

decimal fooTiming = what goes here?
decimal barTiming = what goes here?
```

How can I extract and read the timings of the above steps so that I can then do anything I want to with those numbers?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to see an individual step's information, then you can do this:

```
@{
    StackExchange.Profiling.Timing step;
    using (step = (StackExchange.Profiling.Timing)MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Test Step"))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    <div>
        @step.Name took @step.DurationMilliseconds ms 
    </div>
}
```

The sample should output something like this:

> Test Step took 1000.9 ms

The [`.Step()` method just returns a `Timing` object](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/4206ef09a5d342dd52ab7d355cffe9a704882b01/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfiler.cs#L415) that records its duration when it's disposed - although a bit hacky, the `Timing` object's properties are still accessible.

If you want more information, you can always traverse the `MiniProfiler.Root` and its `Children`, although I've never done it while the profiler is running (i.e. `.Stop()` has not been called).